# Problem with acccess to the JBoss' Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration, jboss

I can't access the Tomcat inside JBoss server. I have JBoss 5.1.1 and started the `web` bundle.

`server.log` looks like this

```
2011-08-11 15:16:55,842 INFO  [org.jboss.web.WebService] (main) Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
2011-08-11 15:17:06,764 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
2011-08-11 15:17:06,765 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) 3.1.2.SP10
2011-08-11 15:17:09,428 INFO  [org.jboss.logbridge.LogNotificationListener] (main) Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.serve
r.MBeanServerImpl@1a7c484[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
2011-08-11 15:17:22,527 INFO  [org.jboss.mail.MailService] (main) Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
2011-08-11 15:17:26,666 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag:JBOSSTS_4_6_1_GA_CP11) - JBoss Inc.
2011-08-11 15:17:26,667 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
2011-08-11 15:17:27,316 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) Initializing recovery manager
2011-08-11 15:17:27,825 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) Recovery manager configured
2011-08-11 15:17:27,825 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
2011-08-11 15:17:27,990 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService] (main) Starting transaction recovery manager
2011-08-11 15:17:29,253 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (main) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.lib
rary.path: /usr/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386:/usr/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
2011-08-11 15:17:29,350 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
2011-08-11 15:17:29,351 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (main) Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
2011-08-11 15:17:29,394 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] (main) Starting service jboss.web
2011-08-11 15:17:29,399 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine] (main) Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.11.GA
2011-08-11 15:17:29,484 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina] (main) Server startup in 133 ms
2011-08-11 15:17:29,514 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws
2011-08-11 15:17:31,253 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.deployers.RARDeployment] (main) Required license terms exist, view vfsfile:/.../z4/jboss-eap-5.1.1/server/web/deploy/jboss-loc
al-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
2011-08-11 15:17:31,273 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.deployers.RARDeployment] (main) Required license terms exist, view vfsfile:/.../z4/jboss-eap-5.1.1/server/web/deploy/jboss-xa-
jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
2011-08-11 15:17:31,282 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.deployers.RARDeployment] (main) Required license terms exist, view vfsfile:/.../z4/jboss-eap-5.1.1/server/web/deploy/mail-ra.r
ar/META-INF/ra.xml
2011-08-11 15:17:32,378 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (main) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:Def
aultDS'
2011-08-11 15:17:33,552 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/admin-console
2011-08-11 15:17:33,790 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (main) Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/admin-console'
2011-08-11 15:17:38,098 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-10) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.xarecovery1] Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery  got XA exception javax.transaction.xa.X
AException: Error trying to connect to provider java:/DefaultJMSProvider, XAException.XAER_RMERR
2011-08-11 15:17:40,485 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/
2011-08-11 15:17:40,569 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console
2011-08-11 15:17:40,631 INFO  [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (main) Loading profile: ProfileKey@8c0d58[domain=default, server=default, name=web]
2011-08-11 15:17:40,650 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (main) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
2011-08-11 15:17:40,678 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (main) Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
2011-08-11 15:17:40,685 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)] Started in 1m:10s:507ms
```

I tried telnet and got those results:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /jbossws HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/jbossws/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 13:21:43 GMT

0


Connection closed by foreign host.


$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /jbossws/services HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="JBossWS Management Console"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 952
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 13:22:30 GMT

<html><head><title>JBoss Web/2.1.11.GA - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/2.1.11.GA</h3></body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And Tomcat's access log is completely empty. Any ideas how to configure it or what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Tomcat listens only at localhost by default. To make it listen at every address, it has to be run like `run.sh -b 0.0.0.0`.